How to handle telling boss about client disloyalty?
We are a recruiting agency. I was tasked this day to conduct in person interviews. I had to convince all candidates, that I am there for them and exchanged phone numbers with one of them, thinking nothing of it. I interviewed like 50 people and I never recall anyones name.
A week or two later someone contacts me on WhatsApp suggesting to skip the agents and work together. At this point I don't know who that is or what it is about.
After a while I figure it out and tell the boss. I figured this might be a trap or loyalty test or something. I thought maybe its not a big deal, so Ill tell him.
Now they seem to be mad at me, completely changed, very cold, not responding.
My wife told me Im stupid for doing it.
But I am the one who told him, he was being scammed, why would I be involved and tell him?

"Now they seem to be mad at me, completely changed, very cold, not responding." - who is "they"? The boss? Or the client who contacted you directly?

Also, could you clarify what "After a while" means, please? What has happened during this "while", and what kind/degree of interaction have you had with the client during that time, until you "figure[d] it out"?

@O.R.Mapper the boss himself actually others don't know about this. I figured it out the same day within the conversation. But it took back and forth and I was thinking about someone else who was supposed to contact me. You can see in the conversation how I talk about industry and this guy is for agriculture.


A week or two later someone contacts me on WhatsApp suggesting to skip the agents and work together.

You stated you work for a recruiting agency, so your "loyalty" and responsibilities are with them.
Somebody writing to you and suggesting to "skip the agents" is something frowned upon and something you will regularly see posted and answered here (and the consensus is that it's indeed frowned upon/unprofessional).
It also sounds a bit odd, as you are an agent of the agency, what was this person expecting to "skip"? Skip you or your coworkers and contact the companies directly?
Not to mention that if you are working for the agency, chances are it's also a breach of your contract and very very surely something that could get you in trouble or fired.
So, I think you did the right thing by telling your boss. If this person/candidate is mad at you or not answering, it's their loss. You shouldn't risk your career and professionalism for a random person, nor should you care or "feel bad" about it now.
I disagree with the opinion of your wife; you did a smart and safe thing, and you don't owe a thing to this person.

"If this person/candidate is mad at you or not answering, it's their loss." - as has meanwhile been confirmed in a comment, it's OP's boss who is mad at OP/not answering.

@O.R.Mapper exactly. I think because I exchanged numbers with him, but I was supposed to be the contact person for these people later anyway. And I see their numbers on the CVs.  I also disagree with my wife, but she was right. It goes "had something to do with" in the suspicious mind, instead of "this guy saved me from a scam instead of profiting". Because it would be very easy to profit off it, although an insignificant amount for me.
